# display specific Fields in gridView in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to display some fields from my database in GridView but my problem is, it show all the field i want in one new field
this is my code

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

and this is c# code

```
                GridView1.DataSource = (from x in db.Products
                                    select x.name + x.phoneNumber + x.proviance + x.description + x.city + x.Address).ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

how to display some fields of a table (not all fields) into gridView in c# in asp.net
With Respect

Comment: How does your markup for the GridView look like?

Comment: Assuming this is webforms, are you autogenerating columns?

Comment: @Spaceman, GridView1 is a control, that is declared in .aspx file. Or at least it should be. Can you show us how is it declared?

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by default GridView generates columns for all fields/columns in the data set it was given. To select what you see you need to turn this off and explicitly declare desired columns:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name of the column in the data set"
             HeaderField="header to show on the UI"/>
        ... and so on for other columns ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```